# Finding colors in images: can Nearest do it?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'm trying to find a way to look for colors in images. Here's a simplified example:

```
tree = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Tree"}]
```

[image: tree image from Mathematica's example data set]

I can see there's blue in there, so I want an xy location somewhere in that sea of pixels. Say I'm looking for a particular shade of blue, which I can supply some approximate RGB values for:

```
Manipulate[Graphics[{RGBColor[r, g, b], Disk[]}], {r, 0, 1}, {g, 0, 1}, {b, 0, 1}]
```

[image: simple colour mixer]

and now I want to find the coordinates of some pixels which have that value, or near enough. `Nearest` might be able to do it:

```
Nearest[ImageData[tree], {0.32, 0.65, .8}]
```

but doesn't - it 'generates a very large output'...

It's the reverse of doing this:

```
ImageValue[tree, {90, 90}]
```

which is OK if I've got the numbers already, or can click on the image. Once the location of the colors I want is known, I can then supply this to functions that require 'markers' - such as `RegionBinarize`.

I feel there must be a Mathematica function for this, but can't find it yet...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Does this

```
Position[#, First@Nearest[Flatten[#, 1], {0.32, 0.65, .8}]] &@
 ImageData[tree]
(*
{{162, 74}}
*)
```

do what you want?

OK, try this:

```
tree = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Tree"}];

dat = Reverse[ImageData[tree]\[Transpose], {2}];

dim = Dimensions[dat][[{1, 2}]];

nearfunc = Nearest[Join @@ dat -> Tuples @ Range @ dim];

Manipulate[
  rgb = Extract[dat, Ceiling[p]];
  posns = nearfunc[rgb, num];
  Graphics[{
    Raster[dat\[Transpose]], Red, Point[posns]
   }],
  {{p, {10, 10}}, Locator},
  {{num, 20}, 1, 100, 1}
]
```

this lets you click somewhere on the image, determines a number of points that are closest (according to the default norm) to the colour of that point, and displays them. `num` is the number of points to be shown.

It looks like this:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Yes, that's good. The Flatten[...,1] didn't occur to me from reading the documentation on ImageData - I thought that was what you got straightaway, but it seems there's an extra level or two to deal with.

Comment: @corm You can do `ImageData[tree]//Shallow` to see the structure of the data `ImageData` produces. You see it is a list of lists of lists(basically, a matrix, each element of which is a vector). This is why `Position` returns both the `x` and `y` coordinates, and this is why you need to flatten the list.

Comment: That's wicked - and intriguingly quirky. Will play with it tomorrow!

Comment: @acl I think all the red points are somehow rotated 90 degrees counterclockwise relative to the points they're referring to - at least, that's something I noticed on a simpler image

Comment: acl, I didn't try your code because `Show[_Image]` doesn't work on v7, but adapting it to `Raster` shows that there is a problem.  I'll try to fix it.

Comment: @Mr.W Yes. I'll get back to this later today (if neither of you fixes it by then).

Comment: The rotation is due to the fact that the pixel at position `{a, b}` in `Show[tree]` corresponds to `ImageData[tree][[H-b,a]]` where `H` is the height of the image, i.e. `H=ImageDimensions[tree][[1]]`. The easiest way around this is to redefine `dat = Transpose[Reverse[ImageData[tree]]];` which basically rotates the image data matrix 90 degrees.

Comment: @Heike belisarius said he didn't expect it with his answer that "went viral" either.  I made the update.  It works with v7 now too, and it should be a little more efficient.

Comment: BTW, if you define `nearfunc` as something like `nearfunc = Nearest[Flatten[dat, 1] -> Flatten[Table[{i, j}, {i, dim[[1]]}, {j, dim[[2]]}], 1]];`, it will return a list of coordinates instead of rgb values so you don't need to use `Position` to extract the coordinates  making the code a bit faster.

Comment: @Heike that's an excellent suggestion; do you want to make the edit?  By the way, why not use `Join @@`?  I think it is clearer.

Comment: @Heike thanks! looking at this code, it's obvious I didn't write it. Congratulations on the n\rightarrow\infty votes for waldo, by the way!

Comment: @Heike, let me show you something or an change: `Flatten[Table[{i, j}, {i, dim[[1]]}, {j, dim[[2]]}], 1] === 
 Tuples@Range@dim`

Comment: @Mr.W, why don't you post a new answer or do this in chat? I can delete my answer.

Comment: @acl because it was your idea, and you deserve the points.  Enjoy. :-)

Comment: @Mr.W but there's no way I'd have written this code! But ok, if you want to slog away for my benefit, have at it :) [the tuples bit is clever]

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Nice. I don't think I've ever used the listability of `Range` before.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few problems with what you are trying to do.

1. You want a position coordinate, not the nearest value itself
2. `Nearest` may return a lot of values rather than just one (use the third argument to specify)
3. `Nearest` wants a list of values to search, not a table

You probably want something like this:

```
Nearest[Join @@ ImageData@tree, {0.32, 0.65, .8}, 1]
Position[ImageData@tree, #] & /@ %
```

```
{{0.321569, 0.65098, 0.8}}
```

```
{{{162, 74}}}
```

---

Don't miss the chance to build a NearestFunction for efficiency, if you are going to be using this dynamically.  Here is a more complete example:

```
tree = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Tree"}]

findcolor[img_Image] :=
 DynamicModule[
  {dat, nearfunc},
  dat = ImageData@img;
  nearfunc = Nearest[Join @@ dat];
  Manipulate[
   Column[{
     Graphics[{RGBColor[r, g, b], Disk[]}],
     Position[dat, nearfunc[{r, g, b}, 1][[1]]]
     }],
   {{r, 0.5}, 0, 1}, {{g, 0.5}, 0, 1}, {{b, 0.5}, 0, 1}
   ]
  ]

findcolor[tree]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: so, are you planning to make this interactive, so that you select the colour and see the 100 points nearest to that colour superposed on the image?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes, you see my problems well, and particularly number 3. - how to use ImageData correctly in functions. As you say, I probably don't know the difference between lists and tables. (I thought they were the same thing... :) Your solution is great! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly an answer to the question, but you might find ideas in this one too:

```
image = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Tree"}];
red = Image@ConstantArray[List @@ Red, ImageDimensions[image]];


threshold = 0.15;
p = ImageDimensions[image]/2;
Row[
 {VerticalSlider[Dynamic[threshold]],
  LocatorPane[
   Dynamic[p],
   Dynamic[
    colour = 
     Extract[ImageData[image], 
      Ceiling[p] /. {x_, y_} :> {ImageDimensions[image][[2]] - y, x} /. 
       0 -> 1];
    mask = 
     Binarize[ImageApply[Abs[# - colour] &, image], threshold];
    Image[
     ImageCompose[image, {SetAlphaChannel[red, mask], 0.5}],
     Magnification -> 1
     ]
    ]
   ],
  Dynamic@
   Graphics[{}, Background -> RGBColor @@ colour, 
    ImageSize -> ImageDimensions[image]]
  }
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: That's really good! And the big colour swatch is a bonus. Thanks.

Comment: @cormullion With a bit of extra work, you can make the swatch into a `ColorSetter[]`, but I didn't want to complicate things (we'd have to make sure that the locator thing doesn't immediately overwrite the colour value when it's set from the `ColorSetter`, and we need to handle `{r,g,b}`, and `RGBColor[r,g,b]` formats separate, without slowing the whole thing down too much.  It's already pretty slow as is, it could be made faster)

Comment: @szabolcs It's quick and smooth on my iMac - at least on the 'tree' image!